# Maven-versions-plugin: regex for negating versions which do not follow a specific tag format

Tags: java, regex, git, maven-versions-plugin

I am using the `maven-versions-plugin` with the `setProperties` goal. I have defined a `ruleset` to compare current property version with available versions containing a git branch name (a git tag), and having the following format:
`<number>.<number>.<number>-<branch_name>.<number>`
for example if the branch is `dev` I would like to match versions like `1.29.0-dev.5` and ignore any other tag like `1.28.0-release.3` or `1.8.0-prere10010.1`.
The rule requires to specify the versions to ignore - so all versions that are not of the form `<number>.<number>.<number>-dev.<number>` should be ignored.
I have tried several regex but do not arrive to the desired result - all versions are in the list of valid versions to compare current version with

```
<ruleset comparisonMethod="maven"
     xmlns="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0
http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd">
<rules>
    <rule groupId="com.abc.de" comparisonMethod="maven">
        <ignoreVersions>
            <ignoreVersion type="regex">(?!^[((\d*)\.(\d*)\.(\d*)\-dev\.(\d*))]$)</ignoreVersion>
            <ignoreVersion type="regex">null</ignoreVersion>
        </ignoreVersions>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

`

Could you please help writing the correct regex?

Comment: You could also match the digit and dots part followed by a hyphen and then assert what is directly to the right is not `dev.` for example `^\d+\.\d+\.\d+-(?!dev\.).*$` https://regex101.com/r/ttZ4nc/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a negative forward lookup, followed by capturing the rest of the string, in case Maven is looking for a full match:

```
^(?!\d+\.\d+\.\d+-dev\.\d+).*$
```